# Getting errors when computing the length of list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. I am trying to find the indices of lists whose length is 4. Here is the code:

```
for i, j in enumerate(list_of_lists):
  if [x for x in list_of_lists if len(x) == 4] in j:
    print(i)
```

Alongside the correct indices, I also get the index of a list whose length is 1. Is there something wrong in my code?  I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: You overcomplicated things and then everything went wrong. Why not a simple `if len(j) == 4:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to collect the indices instead of printing them, it is even simpler:

```py
indices = [i for i, j in enumerate(list_of_lists) if len(j) == 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate over `list_of_lists` like so, `j` is the inner list, so you need to check whether `len(j) == 4`:

```
list_of_lists = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [], [0], [0, 1, 2, 3],]

for i, j in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    if len(j) == 4:
        print(i)
# 0
# 3
```

Comment: Thank you!  Let me please accept nonDucor's answer instead of yours simply because it is more general.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i, j in enumerate(list_of_lists):
        if len(j) == 4:
            print(i)
```

Can you try this code? Actually, i is the index, and j is the value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).